# Multithreaded Delphi database application failing with large amounts of data

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading, delphi

**Overview of the application:**
I have a Delphi application that allows a user to define a number of queries, and run them concurrently over multiple MySQL databases. There is a limit on the number of threads that can be run at once (which the user can set). The user selects the queries to run, and the systems to run the queries on. Each thread runs the specified query on the specified system using a TADOQuery component.

**Description of the problem:**
When the queries retrieve a low number of records, the application works fine, even when lots of threads (up to about 100) are submitted. The application can also handle larger numbers of records(150,000+) as long as only a few threads (up to about 8) are running at once. However, when the user is running more than around 10 queries at once (i.e. 10+ threads), and each thread is retrieving around 150,000+ records, we start getting errors. Here are the specific error messages that we have encountered so far:

a: `Not enough storage is available to complete this operation`
b: `OLE error 80040E05`
c: `Unspecified error`
d: Thread creation error: `Not enough storage is available to process this command`
e: `Object was open`
f: `ODBC Driver does not support the requested properties`

Evidently, the errors are due to a combination of factors: number of threads, amount of data retrieved per thread, and possibly the MySQL server configuration.

The main question really is why are the errors occurring? I appreciate that it appears to be in some way related to resources, but given the different errors that are being returned, I'd like to get my head around exactly why the errors are cropping up. Is it down to resources on the PC, or something to do with the configuration of the server, for example.

The follow up question is what can we do to avoid getting the problems? We're currently throttling down the application by lowering the number of threads that can be run concurrently. We can't force the user to retrieve less records as the queries are totally user defined and if they want to retrieve 200,000 records, then that's up to them, so there's not much that we can do about that side of things. Realistically, we don't want to throttle down the speed of the application because most users will be retrieving small amounts of data, and we don't want to make the application to slow for them to use, and although the number of threads can be changed by the user, we'd rather get to the root of the problem and try to fix it without having to rely on tweaking the configuration all the time.

Comment: Any chance you can set `TADOQuery.CursorType := ctOpenForwardOnly`? It might help with the resource allocation.

Comment: Can you show us the code used to set up the threads, the connections and the queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks you're loading a lot of data client-side. They may require to be cached in the client memory (especially if you use bidirectional cursors), and in a 32 bit application that could not be enough, depending on the average row size and how efficient is the library to store rows.
Usually the best way to accomplish database work is to perform that on the server directly, without retrieving data to the client. Usually databases have an efficient cache system and can write data out to disk when they don't fit in memory.
Why do you retrieve 150000 rows at once? You could use a mechanism to transfer data only when the user actually access them (sort of paging through data), to avoid large chunks of "wasted" memory.

Comment: As I understand, data volume is no problem with lower thread count: `The application can ... handle larger numbers of records (150,000+) as long as only a few threads (up to about 8) are running at once.`

Comment: That's pretty obvious. Threads share the address space of their process. The more thread you create, the less memory space each thread has available.

Comment: What I was looking for was something specific about what exactly was causing the error, as I'm being asked for specific details from my manager. However, my response to him about the number of threads being used, and the amount of data being retrieved per thread seems to be the root cause, so I'm happy with this answer. FYI in some cases we need to retrieve large amounts of data so that the report can be archived on the PC and parsed offline later. However, I believe that the retrieval mechanism can be more efficient, so I'll be looking into this. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you need to store data locally, you should avoid to cache the whole recordset in memory. Read it using a unidirectional, non cached cursor (check ADO cursor options), and store it on disk. Usually situations like this are better handled using the DB library directly and taking advantage of any useful specific features, using ADO a lot depends on the provider quality and the features it implements - and if you use the OLEDB-ODBC bridge it could be even worse ;) But properly setting both ODBC and ADO it could work anyway.

Comment: DevArt (http://www.devart.com/mydac/, commercial) is a Delphi library that allows for direct access to MySQL, but I barely used it once and can't warrant it can solve your issues easily. There could be some OS libraries as well. If 32-bit process memory is an issue and the machine has 4GB+ of memory, you can try to use the /3GB switch (and enable the LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE PE flag) as a stopgap solution, or spawn new processes instead of threads (each 32bit process can use 2/3GB of RAM, up to 4 under a 64 bit OS). With ADO, try a server-side, forward-only cursor. Check ADO doc on MSDN.

Comment: Also ensure you're not using TADOTable - use a TADODataset with CommandType set to cmdText and cursor properties as suggested above.

Comment: Thanks very much for the additional information. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

This makes perfect sense (the fact you're having problems, not the specific errors). Think it through - you have the equivalent of 10 database connections (1 per thread) each receiving 150,000 rows of data (1,500,000 rows total) across a single network connection. Even if you're not using client-side cursors and the rows are small (just a few small columns), this is a HUGE flow of data across a single network interface, and a big hit on memory on the client computer.

I'd suspect the error messages are incorrect, in the same way that sometimes you have an access violation caused by a memory overwrite in another code location.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DBMS, to help with the problem you could use the LIMIT/TOP sql clauses to limit the amountof data returned.

Answer (score 0):

Things I would do:

- write a very simple test application which only uses the necessary parts of the connection / query creation (with threads), this would eliminate all side effects caused by other parts of your software
- use a different database access layer instead of ODBC, to find out if the ODBC driver is the root cause of the problem
- it looks like the memory usage is no problem when the number of threads is low - to verify this, I would also measure / calculate the memory requirement of the records, compare it with the memory usage of the application in the operating system. For example if tests show that four threads can safely query 1.5 GB of total data without problems, but ten threads fail with under 0.5 GB of total data, I would say it is a threading problem